# What counts as "onside" when a ball is kicked from the in-goal area?

Tags: rules, rugby-union

If the ball is kicked from the in-goal area, where does a player have to stand to be onside? Do they have to be behind the kicker (as they would if the ball were kicked from the main field of play) or do they just have to be in their in-goal area?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I've made a substantial edit to this which I *think* is what you were trying to ask. If you were trying to ask something else, apologies and please edit further!

Answer (score 2):

The in-goal is considered part of the playing area (see [Law 1 *The ground*](https://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=1)).

A player can be offside anywhere in the playing area (see [Law 10 *Offside and onside in open play*](https://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=10), verbatim paragraph 2).

The in-goal is treated no differently, and they are offside until they are put onside again by any of the methods outlined in the rest of Law 10.